# Making a unipolar HVPS bipolar safely

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, power-supply

I have a Keithley 5kV power supply (2290 model) that I use for high energy physics experiment. It has resolution of 1V and current resolution of 1uA. The range that it offers is +0V to +5000V via its SHV connectors i.e. unipolar.

I wanted to know if there is a workaround to make the instrument have the same range in the negative range as well. There should be proper internal isolation in the negative polarity otherwise an unsafe negative polarity is not preferred at any cost.

Comment: Some Matsusadas are reversible in the way you describe. Check your manual.

Comment: What do you mean by reversible? Do I have to open it up and switch a component inside?

Comment: Yes, or reverse the entire output module somehow. I was not in the need for negative voltage so I just glanced over it.

Comment: The internal circuitry of Matsusada and Keithley will be completely different.  I want to see if it is possible for Keithley HVPS. I am editing the post to have the user guide of the Keithley machine that I currently have which I want to convert to bipolar.

Comment: Yes, that’s given. My point is that it’s far from unthinkable to have a reversible high voltage power supply. But by bipolar, you mean output + and - simultaneously? That won’t be possible.

Comment: I do not want +ve and -ve voltage simultaneously. I want to configure the instrument to be  permanently into negative polarity. And if a switch can be added to switch polarity safely, then that would be also helpful.

Comment: Ok, then the word causing confusion is "bipolar". If you would be able to flip the polarity as with the Matsusada, it's still a unipolar power supply, just negative.

Comment: Is it possible to open up HVPS units and flip voltage generating component and make it work? If yes, which component has to be flipped? Is soldering involved or is it plug and play. I have not seen any HVPS instrument teardown online so I do not know what components go inside it and which are relevant for switching polarity.

Comment: Again, check your manual or contact the manufacturer.